# Testing for the significance of the difference-in-differences of adj. R²

Tags: regression, stata, bootstrap, goodness-of-fit, difference-in-difference

Is there a way to test for the significance of the difference-in-differences in adj. R²s in Stata?

Let's say I have four subgroups: pre-treatment, pre-control, post-treatment, post-control and I want to figure out whether the difference-in-differences of the adj. R² of the same regression (e.g., R² of Y = b0 + b1*X + e) conducted for each of the four subgroups is signficant.

In other words, is (adj. R²(post-treatment) - adj. R²(pre-treatment)) - ((adj. R²(post-control) - adj. R²(pre-control)) signficant?

I read somewhere that it might be possible to bootstrap the adj. R² of each regression and then test for the difference-in-differences, but I am not sure if this would be an appropriate approach?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is true that you can bootstrap $\text{R}^2$ and $\overline{\text{R}}^2$ (see [Ohtani (2001) "Bootstrapping $\text{R}^2$ and adjusted $\text{R}^2$ in regression analysis"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999399000346)) the procedure you propose will result in having 4 numbers, i.e. the four $\text{R}^2$ or $\overline{\text{R}}^2$ from the regressions of $Y$ on $X$ for the treatment and control groups in the two time periods. In this case you end up like the OP of this earlier [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80277/difference-in-difference-regression-with-only-4-data-points) who tried to achieve exactly that but finally figured out that it could not be done. So even if you can construct a standard error or confidence interval for each coefficient of determination itself, with four numbers there is no degree of freedom left in order to calculate a standard error for the difference in differences.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I would need the standard error/confidence interval (distribution) for the differences between two groups (e.g., R² treatment - R² control) which is probably not computeable for R² (e.g., by random sampling of the differences), or am I wrong here?

Comment: Actually you would need the standard error of the difference in differences. If you had a sequence of each R² measure this is feasible but not with only 4 numbers only.

Comment: Is it feasable to create a sequence of R² difference-in-differences by drawing random observations from the full sample? Let's say, I randomly draw a number of treatment obs. and (matched) non-treatment obs., calculate the difference-in-differences of their R², and repeat that x times to get the distribution of the difference-in-differences?

Comment: I can see where you are coming from though I'm somewhat hesitant towards this procedure, yet I haven't found a good reason against it so far. How do you intend to obtain a standard error for the difference in differences estimate in this way?

Comment: Let's say I randomly draw a number of matched pairs in the pre-period and then calculate an R² for these observations, but seperately for each "bucket" (pre-treat; pre-control; post-trest; post-control). This way I'm able to calculate a diff-in-diff R². Repeating this procedure x times I'd get the distribution, or?